# Using a for-loop to extract elements from the database gives only one result instead of more

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get all the names from my database. for that I run a for loop from 0 to 4 that goes up by 1 each time. But when I run this, only the fourth name appears on the screen, and not all names as I want.

```
public String[] geefMogelijkeSpelers()
   {
    DomeinController dc = new DomeinController();
    String spelerNaam = "";
    String[] namen = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(MapperConfig.JDBC_URL))
     {       
        PreparedStatement qrygeefMogelijkeSpelers = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT spelerNaam FROM coloretto.mogelijkespeler WHERE spelerNummer = " + i + ";");
        try(ResultSet rs = qrygeefMogelijkeSpelers.executeQuery())
        {
            rs.next();
            spelerNaam = rs.getString("spelerNaam");
            
            namen[i] = spelerNaam;
        }
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
            for (Throwable t : ex) 
            {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }                  
     }
    }
    return namen;
}
```

Comment: You don't provide the code that prints the names. That could be flawed too.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, hence as an answer.

First of all it does not make sense to do a "getConnection()" four times. And secondly it would be better to retrieve the complete result set at once instead of sending 4 (actually 3) queries that each retrieve a single row. And even if you prefer to do it the hard way, your loop runs from 0 to 2, not 3 (you test for less than 3, not less or equal 3, resp. less than 4. Expecting four names is a bit optimistic then.

Something like

```
public String[] geefMogelijkeSpelers()
{
    DomeinController dc = new DomeinController();
    String spelerNaam = "";
    String[] namen = new String[4];
    int i = 0;
    String stmt = "SELECT spelerNaam " +
                  "FROM coloretto.mogelijkespeler " +
                  "WHERE spelerNummer between 0 and 3;";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(MapperConfig.JDBC_URL)) {       
        PreparedStatement qrygeefMogelijkeSpelers = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
        try(ResultSet rs = qrygeefMogelijkeSpelers.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                spelerNaam = rs.getString("spelerNaam");
                namen[i] = spelerNaam;
                i++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) { /* executeQuery */
            for (Throwable t : ex) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }     
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { /* getConnection */
        for (Throwable t : ex) {
                t.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }
    
    return namen;
}
```

looks a lot better, I think.

Comment: When I try this, i get this error
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0:

Comment: Oops, sorry. I missed that. I've corrected it by reserving space for 4 names. But be careful, if you have duplicate keys in your table (7 spelers with nummer 0, or so), it'll still crash (it'll be easy to test if you've seen 4 spelers though, and then leave the evaluation of the result set.)